# Collapse List into Unique Combinations Using Index Values

Tags: r, list, algorithm, cluster-analysis, reduce

Firstly, I wish I could think of a better way to describe my problem. I'm trying to take the following example list:

```
lst<- list(c(2), c(1,3), c(2), c(4), c(6), c(5, 7), c(6,8), c(7))
```

And turn it into this:

```
res<- list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), c(4), c(5,6,7,8), c(5,6,7,8),c(5,6,7,8), c(5,6,7,8))
```

*OR* even this:

```
also_good_answer<- list(c(1, 2, 3), logical(0), logical(0), 4, c(5, 6, 7, 8), logical(0), 
    logical(0), logical(0))
```

I've been using a couple `while` statements in combination with `setdiff` to do this, but I'm wondering if there is an eloquent and faster way to do this over a large list?

As always, thank you in advance.
-nate

My method:

```
lst<- list(c(2), c(1,3), c(2), c(4), c(6), c(5, 7), c(6,8), c(7)) # Original List
to_sequence<- 1:length(lst) 
res<- lapply(1:length(lst), function(x) {return(NA)})  # Building Result Object

while(length(to_sequence) > 0){
  tres<- c()
  idx<- to_sequence[1]
  next_idxs<- setdiff(lst[[idx]], NA)
  tres<- c(tres, next_idxs)
  while(length(next_idxs) >=1){
    next_idxs<- lapply(seq_along(next_idxs), function(x){
      lst[[next_idxs[x]]]
    } ) %>% unlist() %>% setdiff(., unlist(tres)) # uses slow setdiff
    tres<-c(tres, next_idxs)
  }
  res[[idx]]<- tres
  to_sequence<- setdiff(to_sequence, tres) # Another slow setdiff
  cat("Length to_sequence:", base::prettyNum(length(to_sequence),big.mark = ","), "\n") 
}

res<- lapply(res, sort)
```

*EDITS*
Updated `lst`:
`lst<- list(c(2), c(1,3), c(2,8), c(4), c(6), c(5, 7), c(6,9), c(3),c(7))`

Giving Desired Output:
`list(c(1, 2, 3, 8), logical(0), logical(0), 4, c(5, 6, 7, 9),  logical(0), logical(0), logical(0), logical(0))`

Comment: I have a better example list, one that might be more helpful. 
`lst<- list(c(2), c(1,3), c(2,8), c(4), c(6), c(5, 7), c(6,9), c(2),c(6))` 

Producing this result:
`list(c(1, 2, 3, 8), logical(0), logical(0), 4, c(5, 6, 7, 9), 
    logical(0), logical(0), logical(0), logical(0))`

Comment: I'm not getting the input -> output logic. For example, why does `c(1, 3)` go with `c(2, 8)`, but `c(5, 7)` does not? Can you update your answer to add this example and explain how to get the result from `lst`?

Comment: These are a list of touches. The first line segment *touches* only the 2nd line segment. The 2nd line segment (second index) *touches* the 1st and 3rd line segment. The 3rd line segment touches the 2nd line AND the 8th line segment. The 8th line segment touches the 3rd line segment...I had an error in my example. I'll fix that. `lst<- list(c(2), c(1,3), c(2,8), c(4), c(6), c(5, 7), c(6,9), c(3),c(7))`

Comment: @nate, how does the third segment (`c(2, 8)`) not touch the 7th (`c(6, 9)`) or 9th (`c(7)`)? Would `c(6, 8)` touch `c(8, 10)`?

Answer (score 2):

The revised question includes commentary that implies that the problem can be interpreted as finding the connected components of an undirected graph described by an input list of vectors of nodes, `lst`, such that `lst[[i]]` is a vector of the nodes connected to node i.

To compute the result, using the input `lst` (defined in the question and also shown in the Note at the end), first build the Rcpp_SimplexTree class graph object, `st`, extract the `connected_components` property, which in this case is `c(1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5)` and replace each component of `lst` with the unique ordered set of nodes in its connected component.

Finally replace duplicate elements in that with `logical(0)` . The ## line can be omitted if duplicates are ok.

```
library(simplextree)

st <- simplex_tree()
for(i in seq_along(lst)) insert(st, t(cbind(lst[[i]],i)))

out <- ave(lst, st$connected_components, FUN = \(x) list(sort(unique(unlist(x)))))
out[duplicated(out)] <- list(logical(0)) ##

# check - see Note at end taken from question for desired
identical(out, desired)
## [1] TRUE

plot(st)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Old

In light of the revised explanation in the question this is no longer relevant.  Use above instead.

I am not completely sure I understand the processing in the question but the following code does not use `setdiff` (although it does use `intersect`) and there are no explicit loops giving the same result for the example. `ok` is TRUE for each element for which all elements before and after it -- the after includes the element itself - are disjoint. `cumsum(ok)` gives a grouping vector - `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)` -- and then we  create a list `L` which contains the group components themselves and finally repeat it the required number of times.  Another thing to try is to see whether Rfast2::Intersect or easy.utils::fastIntersect speeds up the intersect operation.

```
ok <- sapply(seq_along(lst), function(i, i1 = seq_len(i-1)) {
  (i == 1) || length(intersect(unlist(lst[i1]), unlist(lst[-i1]))) == 0
})
L <- tapply(lst, cumsum(ok), function(x) sort(unique(unlist(x))))
result <- rep(L, lengths(L))

str(result)
```

giving

```
List of 8
 $ 1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ 1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ 1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ 2: num 4
 $ 3: num [1:4] 5 6 7 8
 $ 3: num [1:4] 5 6 7 8
 $ 3: num [1:4] 5 6 7 8
 $ 3: num [1:4] 5 6 7 8
```

### Note

```
lst <- list(2, c(1, 3), c(2, 8), 4, 6, c(5, 7), c(6, 9), 3, 7)

desired <- list(
  c(1, 2, 3, 8), logical(0), logical(0), 4, c(5, 6, 7, 9), logical(0),
  logical(0), logical(0), logical(0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update

According to the updated example and expected output, we use `replace` and `duplicated` to nullify the cluster duplicates (see the last line `out <- ...`)

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))
clst <- membership(components(g))
nms <- as.integer(names(clst))
res <- unname(by(nms, clst, sort))[clst[order(nms)]]
out <- replace(res, duplicated(res), list(logical(0)))
```

and we can obtain

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 8

[[2]]
logical(0)

[[3]]
logical(0)

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 6 7 9

[[6]]
logical(0)

[[7]]
logical(0)

[[8]]
logical(0)

[[9]]
logical(0)
```

## Previous Answer

You can use `membership` from `igraph` to detect the clusters

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))
clst <- membership(components(g))
nms <- as.integer(names(clst))
res <- unname(by(nms, clst, sort))[clst[order(nms)]]
```

and you will obtain

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[6]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[7]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[8]]
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

## Graph Interpretation

If you are interested in how the problem is interpreted into a graph, you can use `plot(as.undirected(g))`, which shows

[image]